# What is the probability that the ratio p/q lies between 1 & 2?

Tags: probability, puzzle, density-function

I am trying to solve the following [question](https://brainstellar.com/puzzles/112):

> $p$ and $q$ are two points chosen at random between $0$ & $1$. What is the probability that the ratio $\frac pq$ lies between $1$ & $2$.

There exists a simple graphical method to solve this question that I understood but I tried to solve it using random variables but am getting the wrong answer. Here is what I did:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be random variables such that $p$~$Unif(0,1)$ and $q$~$Unif(0,1)$. Let $f_q(x)$ be `pdf` of Uniform distribution for random variable $q$.
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=P(\frac pq \leqslant 2)-P(\frac pq \leqslant1)$$
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^1P(\frac pq \leqslant2|q=x)f_q(x)dx - \int_0^1P(\frac pq \leqslant1|q=x)f_q(x)dx$$
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^1P(\frac px \leqslant2|q=x)f_q(x)dx - \int_0^1P(\frac px \leqslant1|q=x)f_q(x)dx$$
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^1P(p \leqslant2x|q=x)f_q(x)dx - \int_0^1P(p \leqslant x|q=x)f_q(x)dx$$
>
> (Since $f_q(x)=1$ as it is pdf of Uniform Distribution)
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^1P(p \leqslant2x)dx - \int_0^1P(p \leqslant x)dx$$
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^12xdx - \int_0^1xdx$$
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=2 [\frac{x^2}2]_0^1-[\frac {x^2}2]_0^1$$
>
> $$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=1-\frac 12$$
>
> $$\fbox {$=>P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\frac 12$}$$

But the correct answer is $\frac 14$. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: $P\left(\frac pq \leqslant1\right) =\frac12$ is correct by symmetry, while $P\left(\frac pq \leqslant2\right) =1$ is clearly too high.  The error is in $\int \limits_0^1 2x\, dx$ as neither $p$ nor $q$ can exceed $1$

Comment: That is correct, so it will be that $P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^\frac 12P(p \leqslant2x)dx - \int_0^1P(p \leqslant x)dx $ but then I am getting $-\frac 14$

Comment: $\int \limits_0^{1/2} 2x\, dx$ is also wrong

Comment: I got my mistake. It should be $P(\frac pq \in[1,2])=\int_0^\frac 12P(p \leqslant2x)dx +\int_\frac 12^11dx - \int_0^1P(p \leqslant x)dx$. Now I am getting $\frac 14$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the step where you turn your probabilities into functions, you set

$$P(p \leqslant x) = x$$

That's totally correct - take a look at the graph and convince yourself of that.

But then take a look at the claim that

$$P(p \leqslant 2x) = 2x$$

If you draw a graph of this, you should be able to convince yourself that something is wrong. For one thing, when $x = 1$, you're getting a probability that's greater than $1$.

Hint: You might want to break $$\int_0^1P(p \leqslant2x)dx$$ into two pieces.